# How can I extract specific columns from a CSV file using papaparse and display them using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, csv, javascript-objects

I'm working on a React application, and I have a CSV file that contains data in a structured format. I want to extract specific columns from this CSV file and display them in a table on my React app. Here's what the CSV data looks like:

`1. Summary,,,,,, Meeting title,TestMeeting,,,,, Attended participants,3,,,,, Start time,"9/18/23, 4:15:08 PM",,,,, End time,"9/18/23, 4:17:41 PM",,,,, Meeting duration,2m 33s,,,,, Average attendance time,2m 9s,,,,, ,,,,,, 2. Participants,,,,,, Name,First Join,Last Leave,In-Meeting Duration,Email,Participant ID (UPN),Role "sdadadi, dsada","9/18/23, 4:15:17 PM","9/18/23, 4:17:38 PM",2m 20s,sdadsad@ert.com,asSas@asAS.com,Organizer "SSAS, Udfsdf","9/18/23, 4:15:27 PM","9/18/23, 4:17:41 PM",2m 13s,fsdfsdf@dfsdf.com,fsdfdsfsdf@dsfsf.com,Presenter "dsfsdsf, fsdfsf","9/18/23, 4:15:45 PM","9/18/23, 4:17:38 PM",1m 53s,dsfsdfsf@fsdfsf.com,dsfsdfsf@fsdfs.com,Presenter ,,,,,, .... ....`

I specifically want to extract the "Name" and "Email" columns and display them in a React table. How can I achieve this using React and JavaScript?

I've already tried using papaparse and changing the array values and aplying filters, but I'm facing issues with this. Any help or guidance on how to correctly parse and display this data in React would be greatly appreciated!

code:

````
import Papa from 'papaparse';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Attendance() {
  const [columnArray, setColumn] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [empty, setEmpty] = useState(false);

  const handleFile = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    Papa.parse(file, {
      header: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      complete: function (result) {
        const columns = Object.keys(result.data[0]);
        console.log(Object.values(result.data));
        setData(result.data);
        setColumn(columns);
        setEmpty(true);
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className='container my-3'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-12 text-center text-info bg-dark'>
          Attendance report upload
        </div>
        <div className='input-group my-3'>
          <input
            type='file'
            className='form-control'
            id='inputGroupFile04'
            aria-describedby='inputGroupFileAddon04'
            aria-label='Upload'
            accept='.csv.txt, .csv'
            onChange={handleFile}
          />
          <button
            className='btn btn-outline-secondary'
            type='button'
            id='inputGroupFileAddon04'
          >
            Upload
          </button>
        </div>
        {empty && (
          <table className='table table-hover'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {columnArray.map((col, i) => (
                  <th key={i}>{col}</th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                <tr key={rowIndex}>
                  {columnArray.map((col, colIndex) => (
                    <td key={colIndex}>{row[col]}</td>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
       );
     }

export default Attendance;```
````